# How can I enable 'More Details', when a program crashes?

Tags: windows-7, windows, crash

A few of the gameservers in the game Crysis Wars have been crashing recently, and I tracked the problem down to a certain server modification *.DLL file, which has a bug in it, thus causing a crash.

A few days ago I reinstalled my computer (upgraded to a SATA3 PCI card for my SSD, so I reinstalled to be on the safe side), and now I am not getting the 'View problem Details', in the program crash window (`werfault.exe`).
This is an example of what I'm missing:

[image]

What I'm getting:

[image]

I need to make a tutorial on how to tell the difference between hack attacks and bugs with the server modification, since I need to view the 'Fault Module' in the 'View Problem Details'.

How can I enable the 'View Problem Details'?
I am running on Windows 7 Home Premium x64 SP1.

Comment: Open the Control Panel, and go to **System and Security > Action Center > Change Action Center settings > Problem reporting settings**. Is the **Never check for solutions (not recommended)** option selected?

Comment: @and31415 Yes, I disabled it when I was trying to fix the problem.

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you select **Each time a problem occurs, ask me before checking for solutions** instead?

Comment: @and31415 Yes, I do.

Comment: The **View problem details** button is meant to be available, by default. Did you tweak any system settings? Even if the button isn't there, you can get the crash details through the [event viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and figured it out so I'll post the solution:

Go to **System and Security > Action Center > Change Action Center settings > Problem reporting settings** and choose **Each time a problem occurs, ask me before checking for solutions** and you will get the detailed crash dialog.

If this option is set to **Never check for solutions (not recommended)** instead, then you'll get the dialog without "View problem details" button.